# how to connect a pc with VGA port to an HDMI (only) supported TV

Tags: display, hdmi, vga

Can we connect a pc which has only VGA port (no graphics card available) and a TV with only HDMI port?

If a VGA to HDMI converter is the solution, is it equivalent to a graphics card? Also what is the lowest budget for this? Why do people prefer VGA to HDMI converter when they can buy a graphics card which supports HDMI (I think cost for both VGA to HDMI converter and graphics card is nearly the same)?

Comment: The best solution might be to add a cheap graphics card: at under £20 (UK) this would give a much better image quality than anything based on separate VGA and audio output. Just make sure there are drivers for your OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer has an on-board VGA card. Using a VGA to HDMI cable is only converting the signal. It is not a graphics card on its own, so all performance you have over the normal VGA port is what you'll see on the TV.

It is either this cable (its cheap) or an extra Graphics Card with HDMI support (expensive, but depending on what you want, may be the only choice)

The reason people prefer VGA to HDMI convertors is because the prices are very cheap considering what an actual GPU costs. Usually those people have a GPU that is already good, and getting a low priced GPU with HDMI will reduce performance significantly. Also, not everyone has room for an additional GPU.

Comment: Sorry, my comment crossed with yours, but I am leaving it because of the point about drivers: a PC with VGA only is probably quite old, and its OS likewise.

Comment: @AFH no apologies necessary. :) You do have a point and its better to have too much information than too little. Image quality of a HDMI card will be better than a VGA converter, and it can be a reason to chooce that option.

Comment: If i am right,i found on the net that VGA to HDMI converter costs half that of a GPU of 1gb(even lesser).So will HDMI cable work for me?(it costs very less).I am not concerned with the quality loss.

Comment: You need active conversion (analog signal to digital signal) for VGA to HDMI anyway so the convertor can't be REALLY cheap (otherwise you are probably getting a fake one that will not work at all). It can could indeed cost as much as half of the price of some "economic" graphic cards (e.g. USD $2x vs USD $5x)

Comment: If the current graphic card you have is old and does not have good 3D performance anyway, you might indeed want to consider upgrading the card instead. However, make sure your motherboard has a right type of slot for the card you are going to buy (e.g. pci-e, not sure if you can still get some agp card with hdmi port on the market)

Comment: Example btw: http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-VGA2HDU-Adapter-Portable-Converter/dp/B00JQJV2NA/